# Is there a way to count the total records from a pcollection in python

Tags: python, apache-beam

I need the total count of records received after joins of facts and dimension BQ tables using pcollection .

```py
all_dim_joined_pcol = join_fact_dim_tbl_obj.join_fact_dim_using_cogbk()
```

I expect the count of records from above pcollection all_dim_joined_pcol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to count the elements in pcollection using Count.Globally() . The function belomgs to the class apache_beam.transforms.combiners.

```
counts = self.all_dim_joined_pcol | Count.Globally()
def collect(row):
             temp_list.append(row)
             print ("Count value is :" , temp_list)
             message = "Join done successfully between {}  and {} having count as {}".format(tbl1,tbl2,temp_list)


counts | "printing record count for" + fact_table_name + dimension_table_name >> beam.Map(collect)
```